# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/atmosphere/cpr/AsyncSupportListenerAdapter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I'm trying to push a message from server to client that way :

```
PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
pushContext.push("/registrationEvent", "There was another registration");
```

My problem is that i've the following error

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.primefaces.push.PushContextFactory
```

But I think that this is due to a issue at the initialization of the projet :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/atmosphere/cpr/AsyncSupportListenerAdapter
```

I've try to add jar atmosphere file... Without success. Have I done something wrong ? I'm using glassfish 3.1.

Thanks !

Comment: Where did you drop that JAR file? Do you know that it's not just only one JAR file? Have you carefully read the PrimeFaces *Users Guide* on the Push subject?

Comment: I add the jar file to the whole project. I did that because I thought it was the cause of my problem, according to the last error message I had. I've read the documentation but found nothing to solve my problem... Which informations do you need to tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: Uh, you have put the JAR in root of the project? That's not how it works. It has to go in the same place as your PrimeFaces JAR file, the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: I've add the atmosphere-runtime-1.0.2 jar to the projet using netbeans interface but that's still not working...

Comment: Oww, indeed, and for an unknown reason, i've try with another jar file and now, i've another problem, NoSuchMethodError: org.atmosphere.cpr.MetaBroadcaster.addBroadcasterListener(Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/BroadcasterListener;)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/MetaBroadcaster; but i'm going forward !

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces [MigrationGuide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide) inform: "PrimeFaces Push is reimplemented, PushContext is deprecated, use EventBus instead along with the new Push API."

In this case, on pom.xml, put the 2.2.1 atmosphere version. Probably you are using a old atmosphere version. If you trying to use the Primefaces 5.0, put the code below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```